# Setting up a DisplayLink display on Ubuntu Core running on a Pi3

Tags: usb, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi, displaylink

I am trying to get a DisplayLink (USB monitor [Lilliput UM70](https://www.lilliputuk.com/monitors/usb/um70/)) running on a Pi3-B.  Currently, it is running Ubuntu Core, but I can switch to something else if it makes more sense to run something like Mate.

My Google-Fu has not returned any hints, so I am at a loss.  Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `lsusb` (only the line referring to the display adapter if you know which one) and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: So your question is not related to the actual [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)? Next time when you edit your post (to add the info [requested by David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073766/any-guides-to-setting-up-a-displayport-display-on-ubuntu-core-running-on-a-pi3#comment1763282_1073766), for example), please use the _Edit Summary_ box to save the information what you edited, don’t include it directly in the post.

Comment: Ah, sorry...wrong terms.  DisplayLink, the Video over USB protocol.

Comment: OK, might this be the solution? http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu